# Why is Kinetic.Shape's drawFunc method called twice?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

While trying to create a custom shape using KineticJS (v4.5.4) I noticed that the Kinetic.Shape class drawFunc method is called twice, one more time than what I was expecting given the code below (adapted from  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/). When I run the code below I can see that on my browser console "DEBUG" is printed twice, indicating that the method in question is called twice, why is that??

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      /*
       * create a triangle shape by defining a
       * drawing function which draws a triangle
       */
      var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {
          console.log('DEBUG');
          var context = canvas.getContext();
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(200, 50);
          context.lineTo(420, 80);
          context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 100, 260, 170);
          context.closePath();
          canvas.fillStroke(this);
        },
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the triangle shape to the layer
      layer.add(triangle);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KineticJS may invoke the `drawFunc` any time it chooses. You should design your shape's `drawFunc` to be invoked repeatedly and at any time. The exact question of *why* `drawFunc` is invoked at any particular time is a concern for the library designers, who work hard to make sure you never need to worry about such questions as when and how often `drawFunc` ought to be invoked.

*But* since you're asking... I put together a [modification of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/PMLaT/1/) that captures the `canvas` argument for each call to `drawFunc`.

- It appears that the first call actually draws the shape on the page's canvas: `canvas.element.parentNode` is the container `<div>`, so this is clearly the on-page canvas.
- The second call, however, draws the shape to an *off-page canvas*: `canvas.element.parentNode` is `null`, which means that the canvas is not currently attached to the DOM.

KineticJS could have a working off-page canvas for a number of reasons:

- Perhaps it uses it for rapid animation (i.e., so it can have the next frame drawn on an off-page canvas and then quickly swap it in)
- Perhaps it uses off-screen canvases as image "stamps" of complex shapes (i.e., instead of redrawing a shape that may have thousands of lines and fills, it draws the shape once to an off-screen canvas, and then uses `drawImage` to quickly draw the whole shape, instead of redrawing each separate line)

**EDIT**

In the specific case of KinecticJS, the hidden canvas seems to be [used for event detection](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki#how-it-works) (e.g., determining whether a click has fallen in the bounds of a drawn object or not):

> Each layer has two canvas renderers, a scene renderer and a hit graph renderer. The scene renderer is what you can see, and the hit graph renderer is a special hidden canvas that's used for high performance event detection.

Comment: Thank you all! I guess that the second canvas element that you mention is the hit graph renderer, as explained here: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki. Please, care to edit your answer so I mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @theeDude Good research -- I've added it to my answer.