# KineticJS- Why does it use so many hidden canvas elements?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I am just starting to learn about the canvas element, however I believe that it is double buffered.
Looking through the code for kineticjs It seems that the Kinetic.Stage creates two canvases (not in the DOM) a Kinetic.SceneCanvas and a Kinetic.hitCanvas. When you add a layer to the stage it seems to create 2 more canvases, another Scene and Hit canvas, one of which it displays in the DOM. Why does it need so many overlapping canvases? Or have I misread the code and/or missed the point?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428175/why-is-kinetic-shapes-drawfunc-method-called-twice

Comment: Thanks projeqht, still it seems too many if I have one layer but 4 canvases....

Comment: Hi @sferret consider marking my answer as accepted if it has answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take straight from the [KineticJS GitHub Readme](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki):

> Kinetic stages are made up of user defined layers. Each layer has **two canvas** renderers, a scene renderer and a hit graph renderer. The scene renderer is what you can see, and the hit graph renderer is a special hidden canvas that's **used for high performance event detection**. Each layer can contain shapes, groups of shapes, or groups of other groups. The stage, layers, groups, and shapes are virtual nodes, similar to DOM nodes in an HTML page.

Additionally in the features section, KineticJS features:

> High performance event detection via color map hashing

Comment: Thanks - however it seems to me you would need to be very carefull about adding layers, because surely the performance would soon be poor? Also what are the 2 the stage creates being used for?

Comment: Perhaps if you use too many layers, the amount of canvas' generated might (I'm not sure) outweigh the performance bonuses of using 2 canvases per layer. But why would you need to use so many layers? You can also Group objects within the layers as well and perform operations on the groups instead of the layers!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the stage creating 2 canvases as well. On my KineticJS application I'm only using 1 Layer, and I only see 2 canvases present in the DOM. The nested elements look like this for me: div#container > div.kineticjs-content > div#chart_growth_reference, canvas, canvas